# Sed replace all characters up to but not including {

Tags: json, sed

I have a bunch of files that begin with random text like the following before the start of JSON:

```
> MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6 connecting to: reddit
> 2016-03-09T13:25:25.825+0000 E QUERY    Error: don't know how to
> massage : number
>     at Error (<anonymous>)
>     at DBCollection._massageObject (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:132:11)
>     at DBCollection.find (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:172:47)
>     at (shell eval):1:35 at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:132 MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6 connecting to: reddit {
>         "_id" : "566f8b91cef21a260a66030e",
>         "time_recorded" : 1450150801,
```

I simply want to remove everything before the `{` that begins the JSON. Here's what I tried:

```
sed -i 's/.*{/{/g' test.json
```

This throws no error but also shows no effect. How can I remove all the text above (which will have different random messages in different files) and just keep the `{`?

Comment: `sed` matches line-wise. That pattern will match everything up to the first `{` on each line not from the start of the document to the first `{` in the file.

Comment: please edit your Q to show your expected output, given the above input. And agree with EtanR above about usage of sed. `awk` is probably better suited to solving this, and there are many answers here that would demonstrate the technique, but unfortunately, there isn't a common key word to give your a search string for. You set a flag variable to indicate 'inside of condition A text' and then test that flag. Everyone uses different names for the flag variable. Sorry can't be of more help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sed ':a /{/!{N;ba};s/.*{/{/' file
```

It loops to join all lines until a `{` is found. After that you can apply your `s`command : `s/.*{/{/`